# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject always returns null

Tags: json, api, rest, model-view-controller

I'm trying to consume a soccer API (SportMonks) in my ASP.NET MVC Project. I'm new to this so I'm facing a problem of sending `deserialized JSON` from Controller to View. Here is the code:-

**JSON Response:**

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"name":"Europe"},{"id":2,"name":"Asia"},{"id":3,"name":"Africa"},{"id":4,"name":"Oceania"},{"id":5,"name":"Antarctica"},{"id":6,"name":"North America"},{"id":7,"name":"South America"}],"meta":{"subscription":{"started_at":{"date":"2017-03-20 21:02:56.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"trial_ends_at":null,"ends_at":null},"plan":{"name":"Free Plan","price":"0.00","request_limit":"3,1"},"sports":[{"id":1,"name":"Soccer","current":true},{"id":6,"name":"Cricket","current":false}]}}
```

**Models:-**

```
public class SAPI_Continent
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
public class SoccerAPI
    {
        public IList<SAPI_Continent> continents { get; set; }
    }
```

**Contorller**

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ConsumeExternalAPI()
    {
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        var json = webClient.DownloadString(@"https://soccer.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0/continents?api_token=nAfVFSbRn3x7tP7b840mitMVli48deY0sVndIB6zpae8MquprEivAuH7zplu");
        SoccerAPI continents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SoccerAPI>(json);
        return View(continents);
    }
```

`continents` is always null although var `json` is returning the data normally

**View**

```
@if (Model != null)
{
 <ul>
    @foreach (var con in Model.continents)
    {
        <li>@con.name</li>
    }
 </ul>
 }
 else
 {
  <p>Error</p>
 }
```

How Can I get the values from the `data` part only `id & name` and why the deserialised variable is null?

Comment: public "IList<SAPI_Continent> continents { get; set; }" should be "public IList<SAPI_Continent> data { get; set; }"

Comment: Make it an answer because it solved my problem :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to your "null" question. Your **continents** attribute should be changed to **data**, as this is the name returned from json.